# Django error notification emails going to incorrect recipient(s)

Tags: django

I am trying to get Django to email me 500 errors. I have got DEBUG mode turned off as required, and am sending to a local SMTP server. I'm using Python 2.7.2 and Django 1.5.1.

Django is sending using the incorrect and invalid recipients "n, e":

```
# python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:25
---------- MESSAGE FOLLOWS ----------
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /
From: sender@example.com
To: n, e
```

Extract from settings.py:

```
ADMINS = (
    ('Me', 'me@example.com')
)

SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS = True

MANAGERS = ADMINS
SERVER_EMAIL = 'sender@example.com'
```

Comment: we need to see the code that creates the email, that's where the error is probably

Comment: Your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting includes CommonMiddleware ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ADMINS = (
    ('Me', 'me@example.com'),
    #                       ^ missing comma
)
```

Parenthesis do not create a tuple, the comma does (and empty parenthesis):

```
>> 1 == (1)
True

>> a = 1,
>> a == (1,)
True
```

Refer to [Tuple Syntax](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax) for explanation.

Comment: Protip: always end items in tuples and lists with a comma; easier on the diff too